# what self-written asm don't match bochs

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, gnu-assembler, bochs

Ask what self-compilation and bochs are inconsistent? I want to read something from floppy, got an error.

mycode:

```
Load_FAT:
    and di, 0x0ffe0
    add di, 0x1a # 起始簇号的偏移量26
    mov cx, word ptr es:[di] # cx是起始簇号
    push    cx # 保存簇号, 因为Load_File用到. 空文件的簇号是0, 要处理 # TODO

    mov ax, 0x00
    mov es, ax
    mov bx, 0x8000 # es:bx=>数据缓冲区
    mov ax, word ptr [BPB_RsvdSecCnt] # 待读取的起始LBA扇区号
    mov cx, word ptr [BPB_FATSz16] # 要读入的扇区个数
    call    Func_ReadSectors
```

objdump disas:

```
1e9:    83 e7 e0                and    $0xffe0,%di
 1ec:   83 c7 1a                add    $0x1a,%di
 1ef:   26 8b 0d                mov    %es:(%di),%cx
 1f2:   51                      push   %cx
 1f3:   b8 00 00                mov    $0x0,%ax
 1f6:   8e c0                   mov    %ax,%es
 1f8:   bb 00 80                mov    $0x8000,%bx
 1fb:   a1 44 00                mov    0x44,%ax
 1fe:   8b 0e 4c 00             mov    0x4c,%cx
 202:   e8 7c ff                call   0x181
```

bochs disas:

```
# memory start from 0x10000
000101e9: (                    ): and di, 0xffe0            ; 83e7e0
000101ec: (                    ): add di, 0x001a            ; 83c71a
000101ef: (                    ): mov cx, word ptr es:[di]  ; 268b0d
000101f2: (                    ): push cx                   ; 51
000101f3: (                    ): mov ax, 0x0000            ; b80000
000101f6: (                    ): mov es, ax                ; 8ec0
000101f8: (                    ): mov bx, 0x8000            ; bb0080
000101fb: (                    ): mov ax, word ptr ds:0x44  ; a14400
000101fe: (                    ): mov cx, word ptr ds:0x0   ; 8b0e0000
00010202: (                    ): add byte ptr ds:[bx+si], al ; 0000
00010204: (                    ): add byte ptr ds:[si], cl  ; 004c00
00010207: (                    ): call .-132                ; e87cff
```

because bochs run `mov cx, word ptr ds:0x0`, i got wrong result.

Comment: If you get an error, always post the error you get!  What error do you get?

Comment: There appear to be an additional 5 bytes of `0x00` added to your code. Given that the extra bytes sit right on a 512 byte (low 4 digits of address are 0x200) boundary it suggests to me that you may have read sectors into memory one at at a time. Appears you may have loaded the first sector of the code correctly but the second sector of the file was loaded improperly (possibly the wrong offset specified on the int 13h/ah=2). If you showed your entire bootloader we might be able to see exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Ah is this your current project here: https://github.com/meilihao/write_os/tree/master/1.bootloader/3.loader  ? I noticed in a comment a couple days ago you linked to that github account in a comment. Is that the code that doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know where the source code for the bootloader you are placing in the MBR of your disk image, but when I boot your floppy_loader.img and step through with the debugger you load the first cluster of the .bin file correctly to 0x1000:0x0000 but then the second cluster is loaded at 0x1000:0x0205 instead of 0x1000:0x0200 . It appears this is because you use a retry count of 5 of disk operations and store it in DI, but you also use DI to keep track of the base offset to read a cluster into. You need to fix that code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes, it's my repo. Thank you for your reply. I am starter with asm, and learning how to write a small os. boot is [here](https://github.com/meilihao/write_os/blob/master/1.bootloader/2.loader/boot.s). ok, i will check my code again.

Comment: @MichaelPetch you are right, i fixed the bug.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something stored at least 4 bytes of zeros over the end of that instruction and the start of the next, at address `00010200`.  Notice the *next* instruction in the disassembly is `add byte ptr ds:[bx+si], al ; 0000` which also doesn't match your source or objdump.

Set a watchpoint there in BOCHS to see what instructions overwrite your code bytes before execution reaches them.

Or actually it turns out *nothing* ever wrote there, not even your sector-loader, because of an offset bug in your first stage bootloader.  And BOCHS left that memory initialized to `00`.  (See @MichaelPetch's comments; all credit to him for debugging this for you.)

---

BTW, `objdump` has a `-Mintel` mode so you could get it to use the same syntax as BOCHS and your source.

Comment: Could it be a BPB?

Comment: @fuz: I wondered that, but it seems unlikely since address `00010201` got modified.  (`00010200` was already 0).  So first of all, it's not linear address `0x7c00`, and an MBR has to be able to start with a `jmp rel8` to jump over the BPB.  The BPB doesn't explain stepping on the first 2 bytes of an aligned block.

Comment: I put some comments under the question before I noticed there was an answer. BOCHS doesn't need a BPB, it doesn't do anything nefarious like some real BIOSes loading from USB using FDD emulation.

Comment: I don't have source code to his boootloader but I ran his disk image, and I was right. There is a bug that has him reading the first cluster (in his case one 512 byte sector per cluster) of the file to 0x1000:0x0000 and then when he loops to get the next cluster of the file a bug has him load it at 0x1000:0x0205 instead of 0x1000:0x0200 . The 5 seems to be related to him reusing the DI register for a retry count and for maintaining the offset to read a cluster to. That accounts for an extra 5 0x00 bytes appearing in the middle of his code (happened to be what was in memory previously)